# Запаздывание this.state в React.js

Tags: reactjs

Я новичок в реакте. При изменении *state* после `setState({isDisabled: this.props.isDisabled})` я все еще получаю старое значение в `this.state.isDisabled`. Что я делаю не так?

```
const ButtonRegister = React.createClass({
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    if (this.props.isDisabled !== undefined) {
      this.setState({isDisabled: this.props.isDisabled});
      console.log('props vs state: ', this.props.isDisabled, this.state.isDisabled);
    }
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <button 
          disabled={this.props.isDisabled}  << 1
          disabled={this.state.isDisabled}  << 2         
          type="button">Registration</button>
    )
  }
});
```

Т.е. `console.log()` показывает разные значения для `state` и `props`, а кнопка, если оставить вариант << 2 в своем состоянии запаздывает.

Другими словами я захотел перехватывать `props.isDisabled` и принудительно устанавливать его в `state`. Но после `setState()` контрол не перерисовывается. Или я как-то не так меняю `state`?

Comment: Не надо копировать props в state - потом при изменениях плохо будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вы хотите установить в `state` значение, получаемое из `props`, но метод `componentWillReceiveProps` только лишь предупреждает вас о том, что `props` будут изменены, поэтому, когда вы обращаетесь к `this.props` в этом методе, вы получаете старые значения, новые значения передаются в виде аргумента `nextProps`, который получает этот метод.

То есть:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    //nextProps - это и есть новое значение
}
```

[Ссылка](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) на документацию.

Обратите внимание, что этот метод не вызывается при первоначальном рендере.